# Preceding the name of a typedef with *

Tags: c, variables, struct, typedef

I have recently discovered that you can precede with * a variable when defining a typedef struct in C.

This is an example of what I am talking about ( `*book` being the case):

```
typedef struct item {
    int id;
    float price;
} *book, pencil;
```

I don't really understand how this works.

Are those 3 variables equivalent in terms of data type?

```
struct item *foo;
book bar;
pencil *foobar;
```

Comment: The first is the same as the third but is rather pointless since you made a `typedef` of it. The second is the same as the third, but it is considered unwise to hide a pointer behind a `typedef`. The third is the usual way.

Comment: Your title should be `Preceding the name of a typedef with *`, (`book` is not a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All have the same type = pointer to the `struct item`.

book type IMO is dangerous as it hides the pointer in the typedef making code less readable (for humans) and error prone

Answer (score 0):

Let see a example

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char  *ptr1;   //This all are same
typedef char * ptr2;
typedef char*  ptr3;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(ptr1));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(ptr2));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(ptr3));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8
8
8
```

In 64 bit machine see [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1XvaZYi8)

The output is 8 because it is size of pointer in x86-x64(in 32 bit it is 4 )

In Your case

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct item 
{
    int id;
//    float price;  // I comment this line for clarity
}*book, pencil;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(book));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(pencil));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8
4
```

See [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ryaT0ZtoU)

Thanks.